# Why isn't BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork getting called?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

I have a job object for long running operations that works like this:

```
Class LongRunningJob
    Inherits BackgroundWorker

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDoWork(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
         'do long running job here
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I invoke this like so:

```
    Dim job As New LongRunningJob

    'run it
    job.RunWorkerAsync()
```

This worked fine a year ago, and I moved on to other things.  I had to return to this code today, and when I run it now, the `OnDoWork` override is simply not called.  A breakpoint in there isn't hit, debugging messages aren't written, the method is simply not called, and no errors are thrown anywhere.

I can't think what would have changed that could cause this, since it seems like a low level framework thing.  The rest of the app loads and runs fine, the main window shows (it's a WPF app), and button click events fire.  It's just the background thread method that doesn't fire.  What could be going on here?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing all of the actual code.

Comment: BTW, do you use a Source Code Revision Control system?

Comment: @MitchWheat: It would be hard to answer with seeing it too, because it's a big project.  I'm not sure what I could snip to isolate the problem, and the whole thing would be much too much to ask people to look at. Re: source code, yes, I guess I could go back to the last working code, although I really didn't touch it at all, so I suspect that the problem is environmental somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to fix the problem, although I'm not really sure what's really going on here.  If I left the OnDoWork routine empty:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnDoWork(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
     'no code at all
End Sub
```

it would be called, and if I put basic framework stuff in there, it would also be called.  But as soon as I added a line like this:

```
Dim result = AnotherLibrary.SomeMethod()
```

the routine would not be called.  I looked at the project for `AnotherLibrary`, which is authored by me as well, looked at the `Compile Tab`, the `Target CPU` dropdown and saw that it said `x86`.  I changed it to `Any CPU` and that fixed the problem.  But I'd still like to know what that really means and why it caused this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Common mistake when using BackgroundWorker.  You no doubt are forgetting to check for exceptions.  They get swallowed whole without a diagnostic if you don't write the code explicitly.  Fix:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnRunWorkerCompleted(ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then Throw e.Error
    MyBase.OnRunWorkerCompleted(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: There aren't any exceptions because the code isn't running at all.  I put breakpoints in, debugging statements, etc.  The code is simply not invoked.  But it appears to have been a problems related to CPU target (see my answer).  Do you have any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Having the CPU target wrong is a good way to generate an exception.  Look in the Output window for a "first chance exception" notification from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I got some answer, regarding a similar problem. Trying to add some dlls to my project (c#-wpf stuff), wrapper of c++ code with managed objects, I notices the same problem when the second one has been used.

In my case, it was because the two library used different instance if the same library (Ver. XX.4.1 and XX.3.2). Compiling both the library on the same one, everything worked.